# Limit for integral evaluation

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, physics

I would like to evaluate the follwoing integral for $kr \gg 1$ and in the limit $\Lambda \rightarrow \infty$:
$$ \int_{-2k-\Lambda}^{2k+\Lambda} \frac{\sin[(q-2k)r]\cos(2kr) + \cos[(q-2k)r]\sin(2kr)}{q-2k}dq.$$

The result should be $\pi cos(2kr)$. However, I don't know to to get to this result. What I have tried so far is a substitution $x = (q-2k)r$ which did not help much.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use the property of sines that $$\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B$$

In your case with $$A=qr-2kr$$ and $$B=2kr$$

Comment: I get to something of the form $\int_{-2k-1}^{2k+1}sin(qr)/(q-2k)$ which has as far as I remember no closed form...